# Modern and Current method of setting floating IP's for HAProxy on AWS

Tags: networking, server, amazon-ec2

The material regarding floating point IP's with AWS instances to set up load balancers makes a ton of sense to me, but the problem is that everything out there is so outdated, even the AWS official docs don't work anymore in the slightest with any modern version of Ubuntu. https://aws.amazon.com/articles/2127188135977316

So I'm thinking there's no way people just stopped using multiple load balancers, because the need should still exist, right? Is there anything updated that actually works with Ubuntu 16.04 today with a crazy amount of errors and rewriting of Amazon's own scripts?

Right now I've gotten to the point where the `/etc/profile.d/aws-apitools-common.sh` doesn't exist so I grabbed a copy from an Amazon Linux EC2, but now the `./vip_monitor.sh` script is dumping out "./vip_monitor.sh: 40: [: 3: unexpected operator" constantly and I can't stop it. Should I just try using an Amazon Linux AMI instead?

Answer (score 0):

So I have finally set this up with HAProxy servers on my AWS account.

Basically, you have two servers running HAProxy with almost the same config. And you give a secondary IP to the main server while tying a new, different elastic IP to the secondary private IP.

You'll have to set up the instance to work with multiple IPs, which is explained here https://askubuntu.com/a/995329/57016

You'll also need the awscli, which you can install with the following

```
apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential 
pip install awscli --upgrade --user
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
aws configure
```

Now you can use a command like this one to pull the secondary IP address from the whatever instance it's tied to to your current one

```
aws ec2 assign-private-ip-addresses --allow-reassignment --network-interface-id <your eni ID> --private-ip-addresses 172.31.0.0
```

I have yet to figure out how to check if the HAProxy server running on the opposite server yet as to auto-pull the secondary private IP, but that is definitely a solid place to start.